# Android PagerView page stripe page indicator

Tags: android

I'm wondering how to achieve this page indicator popular in apps when comes to a configuration process. I know there is a custom view for circle page indicator but I'm curious is there any better solution and without need to install external libraries?

I want to be able to create something like:

[image]

Comment: I think you will need the library [viewpagerIndicator] (http://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/). If you want to copy code into library you will need to copy values, attrs. Instead recommend pick library itself

Comment: Now I see there are stripes at the bottom that I want. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can achieve this using android's default viewpager just add one linearlayout above viewpager which contains imageview. To indicate selected page you can use viewpager.onpagechangelistener method. Your layout should be like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >    
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/indicator_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_layout"
            android:background="#343434"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

           <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dot1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/active_dot" 
                android:contentDescription="@string/indicator"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dot2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/inactive_dot" 
                android:contentDescription="@string/indicator"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dot3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/inactive_dot" 
                android:contentDescription="@string/indicator"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dot4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/inactive_dot" 
                android:contentDescription="@string/indicator"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dot5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/inactive_dot" 
                android:contentDescription="@string/indicator"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dot6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/inactive_dot" 
                android:contentDescription="@string/indicator"/>

        </LinearLayout>
       <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/mypager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/indicator_layout" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and your pagechange listener should be like this

```
viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int which) {
            switch (which) {
            case 0:
                setIndicatorImage(dot1);
                break;

            case 1:
                setIndicatorImage(dot2);
                break;

            case 2:
                setIndicatorImage(dot3);
                break;

            case 3:
                setIndicatorImage(dot4);
                break;

            case 4:
                setIndicatorImage(dot5);
                break;

            case 5:
                setIndicatorImage(dot6);
                break;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

public void setIndicatorImage(ImageView selected_img) {
    if (selected_img.getId() == R.id.dot1) {
        dot1.setImageResource(R.drawable.active_dot);
        dot2.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot3.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot4.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot5.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot6.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
    } else if (selected_img.getId() == R.id.dot2) {
        dot1.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot2.setImageResource(R.drawable.active_dot);
        dot3.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot4.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot5.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot6.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
    } else if (selected_img.getId() == R.id.dot3) {
        dot1.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot2.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot3.setImageResource(R.drawable.active_dot);
        dot4.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot5.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot6.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
    } else if (selected_img.getId() == R.id.dot4) {
        dot1.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot2.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot3.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot4.setImageResource(R.drawable.active_dot);
        dot5.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot6.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
    } else if (selected_img.getId() == R.id.dot5) {
        dot1.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot2.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot3.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot4.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot5.setImageResource(R.drawable.active_dot);
        dot6.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
    } else{
        dot1.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot2.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot3.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot4.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot5.setImageResource(R.drawable.inactive_dot);
        dot6.setImageResource(R.drawable.active_dot);
    } 
}
```